# Cannot obtain fields or call methods on the instance of type

Tags: remoting

When I am trying execute a method(client.ServerVersion.OrderCode) on proxy object I am getting message "Cannot obtain fields or call methods on the instance of type". Please can any one tell me how to handle the above situation?